# WordPress 3.5.1 missing parent in permalink for child page

Tags: wordpress, parent-child, permalinks

My site is currently running WordPress 3.5.1

I have created a page (not post) called "Child" with a parent page called "Parent". The child page does not appear to be inheriting the parent page within the permalink structure.

The parent permalink is http://site.com/parent/ and the child page is showing as http://site.com/child/

What I want to happen is for the child page permalink to be http://site.com/parent/child/

I haven't made any changes to the basic structure of the site. It is running the standard "Twenty Twelve" theme.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While creating a page you need to select parent page from page attributes column in the right hand side

Under Settings-> Permalink tab

create custom structure like - `/%postname%/`

FYI - Tested at my end and URL created like - `http://localhost/wordpress/sample-page/page-2/`

Comment: NOTE: I actually had `/%category%/%postname%/` as my permalink structure already, but the link that appears directly beneath the page title when first creating a page doesn't show the parent within the URL structure. As soon as I pressed publish, this updated to reflect the hierarchy that I was looking to achieve.

Comment: @yogidevbear I mentioned all cases what i can think off :) .. good to see you finally made it by clicking :)

Answer (score 0):

@sawpnesh

I'm currently using Hueman Theme but I'm also experiencing like yogidevbear
had. I want to use URL format like http:// example.com/parent/child/. I have checked all the slugs, page names, post names, and no duplication was made. Have permanently deleted all trash. I have set the permalink settings to http:// example.com/%postname%/. I have the child page's page attribute set under its parent page. I also have updated Menu Structure of my child page put under the parent page as sub item. When I view my child page the permalink is changed to http:// example.com/parent/child-2/.

How come it changed from "/child/" to"/child-2/"?

I went back to child page's page attribute and set it back to "no parent".
The pages URL then changed to http:// example.com/parent/ for the parent and http:// example.com/child/ for the child but in the menu the child tab is located under the parent tab.